# Invalid fullName: `model:@each`, must be of the form `type:name`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm setting up a new app with Ember CLI and a Rails backend following [this tutorial](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/05/09/building-an-ember-app-with-rails-part-3.html) but when I set up a route for one of my models, I get the following error:

```
Error while processing route: inks.index Invalid fullName: `model:@each`, must be of the form `type:name`  TypeError: Invalid fullName: `model:@each`, must be of the form `type:name` 
at __exports__.default.EmberObject.extend.resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16772:17)
at Object.resolve [as resolver] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16394:25)
at resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14930:32)
at Object.Container.resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14510:16)
at factoryFor (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:15013:31)
at Object.Container.lookupFactory (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:14617:16)
at Ember.Object.extend.modelFactoryFor (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:74810:31)
at JSONSerializer.extend.extractArray (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:67710:22)
at apply (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:32851:27)
at superWrapper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:32419:15)
```

I've googled around, but I have no idea what it even means. I've checked to make sure I have ActiveModelAdapter and Serializer. The model is not complicated:

My route is `app/routes/users/index.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user'); 
 }
});
```

`app/router.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users');
});
export default Router;
```

and my `app/adapters/application.js` is:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api/v1'
});
```

I'm still pretty new with EmberCLI so i'm not really sure where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out I wasn't using ActiveModelSerializers correctly. Since I was listing all users as a test I thought it would serialize as a list of the serialized data I defined in UserSerializer.

I was doing this in my controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  render json: @users
end
```

When I SHOULD have been doing this according to the docs ([here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#2-for-an-array-resource)):

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  render json: @users, each_serializer: UserSerializer
end
```

I didn't even notice my serializer wasn't being called.

Answer (score 5):

I stuck with similar issue. Only one difference I was used [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl).

The problem was with my rabl configuration:

```
Rabl.configure do |config|
  config.include_json_root = false
end
```

[Ember.js documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_object-root) tells us:

> The JSON payload should be an object that contains the record inside a root property

So, you need to change rabl configuration to:

```
Rabl.configure do |config|
  config.include_json_root = true
end
```

or, pass `root` option inside `rabl` template:

```
collection @orders, root: 'orders'
```